# Semi-disconnected network drives Windows 10 after timeout

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, connection

I'm using Windows 10 in our company for a couple of weeks. Using the GPO (I'm a domain admin myself) we added some network drives for all users of our domain. This works fine.

But.... For some reason, after a while my network drives are semi-disconnected. I use the word semi because the drive is still showing in Explorer (and NO red-cross is added). So it seems to be connected. But when i have a document from the network drive open in for examle Word, and try to save it, Word tells me the document cannot be found anymore, the only thing I have to do is open an Explorer and browse to the network drive letter, and then I can save the document again.

I searched the internet and found several (not working for us) solutions.

Added GPO on our domain:

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
 SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Parameters
 autodisconnect
 REG_DWORD 
 0xFFFFFFFF (4294967295)
```

Also executed on the file-server (where the share is to):

```
netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled
```

Also added to GPO for our domain:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters
KeepConn
REG_DWORD
0xFFFF (65535)
```

Both on my Windows 10 and on the network file-server.
But still I have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

If your network drives are mapped via GPO you should make sure that the mapping "Action" in Group Policy is set to "Update" instead of "Replace".  If your drives are set to "Replace" Windows will routinely disconnect them when background group policy refreshes occur.

Comment: +1: from personal experience, this is probably the answer.